# A shape I haven't included keeps appearing, don't know how to fix it

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, faces, proportional-editing

[image: Screenshot of the weird shape]

The issue I've been having is: this shape (the half-empty green "pyramid") wasn't meant to be there. I was using proportional editing to lower pieces of land (grid object) to make it look like a bit of the land was lowered to build the construction. However, during the editing, a face disappeared and left this weird small pyramid-like structure. The shape can't be seen on the mesh (it rather disappears on edit mode with the grid object selected):

[image: Empty pyramid shape isn't seen on edit mode]

I also can't find any other object containing the shape. It's as if it doesn't exist but it pretty much is there on Object Mode (and on edit mode with other object selected).

Here a view underneath (I have no clue what those shapes there are, and if they have any relation to the issue):

[image: Some shapes underneath]

Some info that may be important for the issue:

- A face of the object was missing when the issue happened
- When I first attempted to create a new face to replace the missing one, it appeared (underneath the land) in a vivid green, as if the sides were reversed
- After deleting the surrounding vertices, I created new faces again and the vivid appearance disappeared. It resulted in the current visualization (like the screenshot)
- After doing so, half of the "pyramid" disappeared, causing the current visualization of the surface (the initial screenshot - beforehand, it was a full pyramid, there werent only 2 faces

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your project, are you able to upload it (or at least the portion with the problem)? You can do it here if you choose to do so - https://blend-exchange.com/ - just edit your question and paste the link they provide into it.

Comment: Is there a multires modifier? It can produce spikes if the base mesh is changed (add/remove vertices)

Comment: @Blunder no, there isn't any modifiers in the shape